# JSF action, value and binding catalog generator

Tags: eclipse, jsf, plugins, parsing, generator

I am looking for a simple tool that generates a catalog of all used action methods, values and bindings. I'm working on a big JSF/RichFaces project and I have lost the overview of the used links to the beans. Therefore I need a tool (would be nice if it is a Eclipse plugin) that generates a simple list of all used EL expressions.

Is there something out there?

Comment: +1: Interesting one, unfortunately no one comes to mind yet. although the extra keyword here is most probably "UML".

Comment: IntelliJ has fairly good support for showing unused JSF methods, values and bindings. Of cause thats the reverse of what you are trying to do, but it could get you started. It also handles Eclipse projects reasonably well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following Unix/Linux command in the directory containing the code:

```
cat * | sed -e  '/#{/!d' -e 's/#/\n#/g' -e 's/}/}\n/g' | sed '/#/!d' | sort | uniq
```

If you are using Windows, install Cygwin and run it with that. 
Only works in the one directory at the moment but shouldnt be too hard to make the cat call recursive.